# Closing app with wix file and custom action before uninstall

Tags: xml, electron, wix, windows-installer, electron-builder

I need to close an app before uninstall, using custom action.

We have an electron app with and as a builder we use electron-builder, and in the process of compiling I rewrite wix template file to receive specific behaviour from msi installer.

When I'm trying to close application with custom action, i still receive a pop-up window which asking me to close all instances of app before continue to uninstall process

Please help me correct Custom action or propose other method (maybe i can somehow add close app extension) that can help me to reach desired behaviour

I tried this code, but as i explained it still showing pop-up on uninstall

```xml
<CustomAction Id="KillApp" Directory="TARGETDIR" Execute="immediate" Return="asyncWait" ExeCommand="cmd.exe /c taskkill /F /IM Test-app.exe" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="KillApp" Before="InstallValidate">Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I expect that my electorn app will be closed before uninstall process will start and it will not show up any pop-ups